# APK upload on Google Play failed

Tags: cordova, google-play

So, I am having a weird issue. Well, each time I upload my app on Play Store, it says:

**Upload failed
You uploaded an APK file whose AndroidManifest.xml contains multiple `<application>` tag entries. There must be only one.**

Here is my `<application>` section in my XML file:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></application>
</gap:config-file>
```

As you see, I have only one `<application>` tag. How I am getting this mistake?

I have used Phonegap Build. Moreover, I have submitted an app before with the same codes included but never got an issue. I do not know why this one I am getting problem.

Help!

Comment: We need to see all your manifest file (your entire `manifest` section). There's probably another `application` section in there.

Comment: I am using Phonegap Build, and everything goes on a config/XML file. There is no such other application tag, trust me. Only the code above has the application tag.